# How to profile SQL queries using ADODB?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I'm using [ADODB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodb/) library for sql manipulation, but i'm wondering if there is way to display each:

- Query Syntax
- Processing Time
- Fetched Rows
- Affected Rows

In a way like firebug in the bottom of pages during development which means it would be super useful to improve the performance and debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to write your own output for firebug console.
Fetch needed details about queries with using
`adodb_backtrace($e->gettrace());`
`Affected_Rows( )`
`LogSQL(true)`

```
$perf = NewPerfMonitor($conn);`
$perf->SuspiciousSQL();
$perf->ExpensiveSQL();`
```

and more...

according to the manual
http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm
http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-perf.htm

try it using these links

http://snipplr.com/view/7963/show-mysql-query-log-with-firebug/
http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/09/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-i